# Accessing inner function variable in outer function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to access the value of inner function variable outside. But I cannot use it outside the inner function. My code is-

```
function t9(){
   var start=298;
   var diff;
   function count(){
      var end=400;
      var diff=end-start;
   } 
   return diff;
}
```

Comment: You're declaring `count`, but never calling it. Is that intentional?

Comment: how you are calling t9() and count().. It depends

Answer (score 4):

Dont re-declare the variable, so instead of : `var diff=end-start;` write- `diff=end-start;`

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
function t9()
  var start=298;
  return count(start);
}

function count(start){
   var end=400;
   var diff=end-start;
   return diff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function t9(){
   var start=298;
   var diff;
   var end;
   function count(){

      end=400;
      diff=end-start;
   } 
   count();
   alert(diff);
}
t9();
```